# is "contrary" used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> English teachers are notorious for being picayune; however, the English language is so nuanced and sophisticated that often such teachers are not being **contrary** but are only adhering to the rules.

What is contrary to what?

Comment: This usage should be listed in a dictionary; did you look it up to see what was going on?

Comment: I believe it is that the teachers are not being contrary to the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> English teachers are contrary.

In the example "contrary" is a state, so there is no direct object. In context, it refers to the English teachers; that they are disagreeable or have opposite views compared with others.